# Dialplan code error when redirecting calls

Tags: asterisk, dialplan

I have generated a dialplan, where you call one function or another, depending on what time you call.

My problem comes when it goes from morning shift to afternoon shift

Like i said earlier i create a time slot.

```
n,gotoiftime(8:00-15:00,mon-thu,*,*,?atencionPublico)
n,gotoiftime(15:00-17:30,mon-thu,*,*,?atencionPublicoAttTardes)

n(atencionPublicoAttTardes),BackGround(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/ocm/NavarraHorario)
n,waitexten(5)
n,Set(ACTION=FUNC_SKILL NA_IncidenciasTardes)
n,AGI(agi:async)
exten => 1,1,Set(ACTION=FUNC_DIALPLAN NavarraPulsa1)
n,AGI(agi:async)

;*******************************************************
n(atencionPublico),BackGround(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/ocm/Navarra)
n,waitexten(5)
n,Set(ACTION=FUNC_SKILL NA_Incidencias)
n,AGI(agi:async)
exten => 1,1,Set(ACTION=FUNC_DIALPLAN NavarraPulsa1)
n,AGI(agi:async)
```

My problem is that I have to change the order of the call to make it work.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Really not clear what is "change the order", how, and why it not works.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `gotoiftime` will continue executing dialplan if your condition is false. If your dialplan is exactly as shown, you don't have a handler for Fri-Sun, before 8am, or after 5:30pm. It would simply continue executing the next step when both `gotoiftime` conditions are false, meaning it would go to the next step, which is `n(atencionPublicoAttTardes)`.

In order to be certain that your condition for `15:00-17:30,mon-thu,*,*,` is correct, try adding a step between the conditions and the afternoon handler, like for example `n,Hangup()` (don't use this live of course, just for testing).

If you find that it's hanging up instead of executing the afternoon dialplan, the problem is actually the condition in `gotoiftime`, not the order of the handlers.

Normally the order shouldn't matter. This is the only reason I can think that it would affect the result.

Comment: I think you missed, that "exten => 1,1," is twiced. Anyway, this dialplan have multiple errors and no way said which exactly errors want fix TS(and how).